# Vagrant provision shell, auto install Linuxbrew with command

Tags: bash, shell, vagrant, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I'm using this vagrantfile:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"

  ...bla bla bla bla bla...

    config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh"

end
```

Since I want to install Linuxbrew I have in my **provision/setup.sh** this code:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --yes git-all libreadline-dev build-essential curl git m4 python-setuptools ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

# or maybe also this: (but nothing anyway):
# sudo git clone https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew.git /home/vagrant/.linuxbrew

export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH

brew doctor
```

But I retrieve errors:

```
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 35: brew: command not found
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an issue how you run your script - as you run with `config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh"` vagrant will run it as `root` user and so you do not need sudo

however you should really run it as your user so do `config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provision/setup.sh", privileged: false`

also the export will not be saved for your future session so add it to `.bashrc` file something like `echo PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH >> .bashrc` so the final script would look like

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --yes git-all libreadline-dev build-essential curl git m4 python-setuptools ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

yes | ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"

echo PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc    
export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
brew doctor
```

The export is needed if you run brew from the script but note that brew doctor will likely ends up with warning and do not return so you might end up seeing vagrant message as

```
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

and finally for the original error, @BMW gets all credit adding `yes |` to the command will default the enter key on the question

Comment: And if I wanna run everything as root and just linuxbrew as "vagrant" normal user?

Comment: honestly I never did this way but I guess `su -l vagrant -c "brew doctor"` would work; in this case also make sure if you do the echo thing to have full path otherwise it will go to root

Comment: Anyway, also with `privileged: "false"` in Vagrantfile I get: `==> default: Don't run this as root!` and it down't work!

Comment: sorry - remove the quote, must be privileged: false so it is the value false and not a string

Comment: Ok, before your accept answer... Now it works, but I can't fix brew in bash. I try this: `echo PATH $PATH
[ -f ~/.bashrc ] || touch ~/.bashrc
grep 'PATH=/home/vagrant/.linuxbrew/bin' ~/.bashrc || echo 'export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH' | tee -a ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
. ~/.bashrc
echo PATH $PATH
brew doctor
` it says to me: `==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 30: brew: command not found`

Comment: editing answer as the simple `echo PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bashrc` is working for me

Comment: Last question, I swear. I'm trying to launch `gem install bundler` from setup.sh. So I need to change directory with `cd` to install it in `/vagrant` and i'm trying with: `echo 'alias goHome="cd /vagrant"' >> .bashrc` then `. ~/.bashrc` and then `goHome` and then `gem install bundler`, but I have this error: ` /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 76: goHome: command not found
==> default: ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
==> default:     Permission denied - /var/lib/gems`. What to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102571/discussion-between-john-sam-and-frederic-henri).

Comment: you need to install with sudo `sudo gem install bundler` will work

Comment: Nope, because it install it in ruby -v 1.9 which is the default "system" version. Not rbenv 2.3.0 that I install with `rbenv install 2.3.0` and `rbenv global 2.3.0` and `rbenv local 2.3.0` before `sudo gem install bundler`. And why I need sudo if in `vagrant ssh` I use only `gem install bundler` in rbenv 2.3.0?

Comment: at this stage, I think you'll be better off making a new question to ruby community and make sure you describe all the things you installed

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess. Add `yes` before the ruby command

```
yes | ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

Comment: Now it says: `==> default: Don't run this as root!
==> default: /tmp/vagrant-shell: line 35: brew: command not found`

Comment: @JohnSam - Would love to hear if a solution was ever found to this.